# Is there any website available so that i can compare lot of translations on Tanach?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet, translation

**I would like to know a good website so that i can compare different translations (English) of the Tanach per line/paragraph.**

What I'm looking for is a website similar to http://quran.com, where you can compare different translations of the Quran per line/paragraph.

It will be very helpful if you provide me a similar site for the Tanach.

Comment: Biblehub and biblegateway do this, but they include a lot of christian translations, and of course do not limit themselves to Tanach. I'm not aware of any Jewish-focused site which does this.

Comment: suhail, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here!

Comment: sefaria.org has a bunch of Jewish translations, but not on the same page at once...as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Yishai [biblehub](http://biblehub.com/) is really helpful for me. it is what i am looking for bible.

Comment: @Gary thanks. that is a nice site. that seems enough for me now.

Comment: @suhail - I thought there was a way to get sefaria to display a bunch of translations/commentaries on a page, but I can't seem to figure it out now...

Comment: I created a website with Hebrew and paleo Hebrew Torah https://suhailvs.github.io/torah

Answer (score -1):

It's not a Jewish site, but you might find exactly what you are looking for at http://www.e-sword.net/.  You download it, and when you open it up you'll find a bunch of English translations.   It's a very powerful program, with all sorts of cross reference features...not bad for free!

Comment: Well, it IS a site "similar to quran.com", which isn't a Jewish site, either.  It does have the different English translations per line/paragraph the questioner asked for. Did I/it offend someone's delicate sensibilities?

Comment: It is a software, not a website